# With pandas.DataFrame.replace in python how to replace all ä with ae?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

With pandas.DataFrame.replace in python how to replace all ä with ae only the ones that are in between ${}?

Below is my Python code that I tried with but it didn't worked:

`df.replace({'Desc': r'\$\{.*ä\}'} , {'Desc': r'\$\{.*ae\}'}, regex=True)`

- As a first e.g.

*Actual Result:*
Lorem Ipsum is ä simply dummy text ${M**ä**nner} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ä.

*Expected Result:*
Lorem Ipsum is ä simply dummy text ${M**ae**nner} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ä.

- As a second e.g. where ä is occurring multiple time

*Actual Result:*
Lorem Ipsum ${fl**ä**chenm**ä**ßig} is ä simply dämmy ${fl**ä**chenm**ä**ßig} text

*Expected Result:*
Lorem Ipsum ${fl**ae**chenm**ae**ßig} is ä simply dämmy ${fl**ae**chenm**ae**ßig} text

> Please note that the examples I had mentioned do not have any meaning.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please check again the question I've clarified more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
import re
rgx = re.compile(r'(\$\{.+?\})')
df['Desc'] = df['Desc'].apply(lambda s: [s := s.replace(rep, rep.replace('ä', 'ae'), 1) for rep in rgx.findall(s)][-1])
```

Output:

```
                                                                                Desc
0  Lorem Ipsum is ä simply dummy text ${Maenner} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ä.
1             Lorem Ipsum ${flaechenmaeßig} is ä simply dämmy ${flaechenmaeßig} text
```

Comment: I've used a regular expression to replace the text only between ${}. I'll correct this above.

Comment: @Seifeddine check now :)

Comment: Works :) but what if there is multiple letters in between the ${} as e.g. ${flächenmäßig} ?

Comment: Sorry I've forgotten to mention that at the beginning. I've updated that now.

Comment: @Seifeddine okay, I updated it. Check now :)

Comment: Hi richardec, do you know why I am getting this error message when I run the script with a great amount of data? "Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range"

Comment: Not sure that I had that issue because of a large number of data because I've just tried it with large data but dummy and it works it is only doesn't work with the real data that I want to run the script over.